# Python, issue with ties using argsort

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have the following problem with sorting a 2D array using the function `argsort`.

More precisely, let's assume I have 5 points and have calculated the euclidean distances between them, which are stored in the 2D array `D`:

```
D=np.array([[0,0.3,0.4,0.2,0.5],[0.3,0,0.2,0.6,0.1],
           [0.4,0.2,0,0.5,0],[0.2,0.6,0.5,0,0.7],[0.5,0.1,0,0.7,0]])
D
array([[ 0. ,  0.3,  0.4,  0.2,  0.5],
       [ 0.3,  0. ,  0.2,  0.6,  0.1],
       [ 0.4,  0.2,  0. ,  0.5,  0. ],
       [ 0.2,  0.6,  0.5,  0. ,  0.7],
       [ 0.5,  0.1,  0. ,  0.7,  0. ]])
```

Each element `D[i,j]` (i,j=0,...,4) shows the distance between point **i** and point **j**. The diagonal entries are of course equal to zero, as they show the distance of a point to itself. However, there can be 2 or more points which overlap. For instance, in this particular case, point **4** is located in the same position of point **2**, so that the the distances `D[2,4]` and `D[4,2]` are equal to zero.

Now, I want to sort this array `D`: for each point **i** I want to know the indices of its neighbour points, from the closest to the furthest one. Of course, for a given point **i** the first point/index in the sorted array should be **i**, i.e. the the closest point to point **1** is **1**. I used the function `argsort`:

```
N = np.argsort(D)
N
array([[0, 3, 1, 2, 4],
       [1, 4, 2, 0, 3],
       [2, 4, 1, 0, 3],
       [3, 0, 2, 1, 4],
       [2, 4, 1, 0, 3]])
```

This function sorts the distances properly until it gets to point **4**: the first entry of the 4th row (counting from zero) is not **4** (`D[4,4]=0`) as I would like. I would like the 4th row to be `[4, 2, 1, 0, 3]`. The first entry is **2**, because points **2** and **4** overlap so that `D[2,4]=D[4,2]`, and between the same value entries `D[2,4]=0` and `D[4,2]=0`, `argsort` selects always the first one.

Is there a way to fix this so that the sorted array `N[i,j]` of `D[i,j]` always starts with the indices corresponding to the diagonal entries `D[i,i]=0`?

Thank you for your help,
MarcoC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to fill the diagonal elements with something lesser than global minimum and then use `argsort` -

```
In [286]: np.fill_diagonal(D,D.min()-1) # Or use -1 for filling
           # if we know beforehand that the global minimum is 0

In [287]: np.argsort(D)
Out[287]: 
array([[0, 3, 1, 2, 4],
       [1, 4, 2, 0, 3],
       [2, 4, 1, 0, 3],
       [3, 0, 2, 1, 4],
       [4, 2, 1, 0, 3]])
```

If you don't want the input array to be changed, make a copy and then do the diagonal filling.

Comment: You can just fill it with `-1`, no?

Comment: @StefanPochmann That's what I suggested at the start. But then I considered that off diagonal elements might be lesser than 0s too. So, to make it generic introduced `D.min()-1`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import numpy as np

D = np.array([[ 0. ,  0.3,  0.4,  0.2,  0.5],
              [ 0.3,  0. ,  0.2,  0.6,  0.1],
              [ 0.4,  0.2,  0. ,  0.5,  0. ],
              [ 0.2,  0.6,  0.5,  0. ,  0.7],
              [ 0.5,  0.1,  0. ,  0.7,  0. ]])

s = np.argsort(D)
line = np.argwhere(s[:,0] != np.arange(D.shape[0]))[0,0]
column = np.argwhere(s[line,:] == line)[0,0]
s[line,0], s[line, column] = s[line, column], s[line,0]
```

Just find the lines that don't have the dioganal element in front using  `numpy.argwhere`, then the column to swap and then swap the elements. Then `s` contains what you want in the end.

This works for your example. In a general case, where `numpy.argwhere` can contain several elements, one would have to run a loop over those elements instead of just typing `[0,0]` at the end of the two lines of code above.

Hope I could help.